# How to run long background processes - Heroku App - Dash Python

Tags: python, function, heroku, plotly-dash, worker

I'm working on a **Baseball Simulator** app with Dash. It uses a SGD model to simulate gameplay between a lineup and a pitcher. The app (***under construction***) can be found here: https://capstone-baseball-simulator.herokuapp.com/ and the repo: https://github.com/c-fried/capstone_heroku

**To summarize the question:** I want to be able to run the *lineup optimizer* on the heroku server.

*There are potentially two parts to this: 1. Running the actual function while avoiding timeout. & 2. Displaying the progress of the function as it's running.*

---

There are several issues I'm having with solving this:

1. The function is expensive and cannot be completed before the 30-second timeout. (It takes several minutes to complete.)

For this, I attempted to follow these instructions (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq) by creating a `worker.py` (still in the repo), moving the function to the external `.py`...etc. The problem I believe was that the process still was taking too long and therefore terminating.

2. I'm (knowingly) using a `global` variable in the function which works when I run locally but does not work when deployed (for reasons I somewhat understand - *workers don't share memory* https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks)

I was using a `global` to be able to see live updates of what the function was doing as it was running. Again, worked as a hack locally, but doesn't work on the server. I don't know how else I can watch the progress of the function without some kind of global operation going on. I'd love a clever solution to this, but I can't think of it.

---

I'm not experienced with web apps, so thanks for the advice in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach to solve this problem is to,

- Run the long calculation asynchronously, e.g. using a [background service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing)
- On completion, put the result in a shared storage space, e.g. a redis cache or an S3 bucket
- Check for updates using an `Interval` component or a `Websocket` component

I can recommend [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) for keeping track of the tasks.